# Need to scan db and either display a message or update item

Tags: node.js, react-native, aws-lambda

I'm using Dynamo DB in AWS. I've reviewed some of the documentation and now have a semi functional lambda function. I'm not too familiar with nodejs but figured "it's javascript! just treat it like that!".

So this function is about scanning the database in the `user_handle` db and if a user already has an existing handle, then alert the user that the handle already exists. If the handle does not exist, then update the `user_handle` item.

So my function updates the handle if it doesn't exist, but if it does, then I need to see this in my response.

Here's my lambda function:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk'); const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-west-1'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    let e = JSON.parse(event.body)


    var params = {
      TableName: event.stageVariables.user,
      Key: { 'userId' : e.userId },
      UpdateExpression: 'set user_handle = :user_handle',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':user_handle' : e.user_handle,
      }
    };

    var scanParams = {
      TableName : event.stageVariables.user,
      FilterExpression : 'user_handle = :user_handle',
      ExpressionAttributeValues : {':user_handle' : e.user_handle}
    };



    docClient.scan(scanParams, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
          console.log("ERROR:", err);
          let response = {
              "statusCode": err.statusCode,
              "headers": {},
              "body": JSON.stringify(err)
          }
          console.log("RESPONSE", response)
          callback(response)
      } else {
          let response = {
              "statusCode": 200,
              "body": JSON.stringify({"Success": true})
          }
          callback(null, response)
          // console.log("RESPONSE", response)
          // console.log("DATA", data)
          if( data.Count >= 1 ){

              let handleExistsResponse = {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "body": JSON.stringify({"Success": false})
              }
              console.log("HANDLE IT", handleExistsResponse)
              callback(null, handleExistsResponse)


          } else {

              docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
                  if (err) {
                      console.log("ERROR:", err);
                      let response = {
                            "statusCode": err.statusCode,
                            "headers": {},
                            "body": JSON.stringify(err)
                      }
                      console.log(response)
                      callback(response)

                  } else {
                      let response = {
                          "statusCode": 200,
                          "body": JSON.stringify({"Success": true})
                      }
                      callback(null, response)
                  }
                });

          }
      }
    //   console.log("DATA", data);
    });


     };
```

Here's the DB function in my React Native App:

```
export async function createUserHandle() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let { auth } = store.getState()

    let reqBody = {
      userId: auth.user.username,
      user_handle: auth.user_handle,
    }


    let path = '/u/create-user-handle'
    let myInit = {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: reqBody,
      // response: true,
    }

    API.post(apiName, path, myInit)
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log('response from user handle', resp)
        resolve(resp)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.warn('Create USER Handle ERROR', error)
        reject(error)
      })
  })
}
```

In the Lambda I was hoping that `if (data.Count >= 1){}` can give me a response of false coming from

```
let handleExistsResponse = {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "body": JSON.stringify({"Success": false})
              }
```

and if it is false, then I can display the appropriate message on the front end. but the response i'm getting is true if i console log it on the front end.

( also, wouldn't mind a code review on this, probably my 3rd time writing a function like this. thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out..

```
} else {
          let response = {
              "statusCode": 200,
              "body": JSON.stringify({"Success": true})
          }
          callback(null, response)
          // console.log("RESPONSE", response)
          // console.log("DATA", data)
          if( data.Count >= 1 ){
```

The callback happening after the response kept the next call back after the condition to go through. I'm now getting the response I needed. Feels good :D

Still wouldn't mind a code review :)